# Setting up firebase v3 custom auth with php

Tags: php, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set up  custom auth with the new firebase sdk from google following those guidelines : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server#use_a_jwt_library
In the samble code it says :

> Get your service account's email address and private key from the JSON key file

Unfortunately I have not idea where to get this json file. If I go to my firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/) I manage to donwload a json file but it does not contain any email adress and private key.

I managed to find a json file that contains an email adress and a private key in my google cloud platform console (http://console.cloud.google.com) by goind into the "API Manager > Credentials" menu. Surprisingly my firebase app was showed there. I copy and pasted the email and key into the sample code, then I got this error :

> Warning: openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key in /volume1/web/yeti/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php on line 183 Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DomainException' with message 'OpenSSL unable to sign data' in /volume1/web/yeti/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php:185 Stack trace: #0 /volume1/web/yeti/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php(154): Firebase\JWT\JWT::sign('eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Q...', NULL, 'RS256') #1 /volume1/web/yeti/jwt.php(21): Firebase\JWT\JWT::encode(Array, NULL, 'RS256') #2 /volume1/web/yeti/jwt.php(24): create_custom_token('1234', false) #3 {main} thrown in /volume1/web/yeti/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php on line 185

Does someone has an idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: A Firebase project is "just" a special type of Google Cloud Platform project, so your Firebase projects indeed are supposed to show up in the Google Cloud Platform console. On creating a service account, see the first paragraph in [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start#server-sdk-authentication)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still not working. Did what explained in the link. Still getting the same error. _( Warning: openssl_sign(): supplied key param cannot be coerced into a private key )_

Answer (score 8):

Did you find the solution ? Still experiencing the same issue ! Works with HS256 and doesn't with RS256. Is it google cloud kind of limitation ?

---

Thank you so much ! @dbburgess

Problem: Was using the wrong key and email. These should be generated in the Google Cloud credentials section that corresponds to the Firebase project.

Solution:

- Go to 'console.cloud.google.com'.
- Select the related Firebase project.
- Then 'API Manager' -> 'Credentials'.
- 'Create Credentials' -> 'Service Account Key' -> Choose JSON.
- The created file will contain the needed 'private_key' & 'client_email'.

Fill the values:

$service_account_email = "autogeneratedemail@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
  $private_key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nSoneVeryVeryLongKey=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
  $uid = 'UserToUseInFirebaseRules';
  $is_premium_account = $uid;

You shouldn't need to change anything in the "create_custom_token" function, maybe the expiration date/time according to your needs.

Then call the function:

```
create_custom_token($uid, $is_premium_account);
```

Comment: What function is create_custom_token?

Comment: That's taken from the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I'm doing, and it works fine. What you provide in the `claims` array is what shows up on `auth` in the security rules. The email and key come from the json file you get when you [create a service account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth) (see: *Before you begin* section).

```
$userId = '1234';
$email = 'sample@email.com';
$key = 'giant_key_goes_here';

$payload = [
    'iss' => $email,
    'sub' => $email,
    'aud' => 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit',
    'iat' => time(),
    'exp' => time() + 60 * 60,
    'uid' => $userId,
    'claims' => [
        'uid' => $userId,
    ],
];

$token = JWT::encode($payload, $key, 'RS256');
```

It's worth noting, the format on the keys is a little tricky...Your key will look something like this (just an example key):

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

You may need to do a little fancy formatting, this is essentially what I did:

```
$key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\n37sJ5QsW+sJyoNde3xH8vdXhzU7eT82D6X/scw9RZz+/6rCJ4p0=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
```

Note the line breaks are turned into `\n`, and it is all smushed onto one line. There are various ways of accomplishing it, but...Based on the error you got, something like this may be the problem.

Comment: hello @dbburgess can you help how to change private key into a single line string? thanks

Answer (score 4):

Found my self what was wrong !
The sample php code from the documentation is buggy. Instead of

```
return JWT::encode($payload, $private_key, "RS256");
```

use

```
return JWT::encode($payload, $private_key, "HS256");
```

Edit :
Actually, it was just the sample php code from google firebase doc that was completely buggy. it was passing an empty key to php-jwt. Looks like they updated it today and it's working fine :)

Comment: Great to hear that you found the problem and thanks for reporting back! I'll add a note that we need to update the documentation.

Comment: There is also a syntax error in the sample php code in this line : `"claims" => array(
          "premium_account" => $is_premium_account
      ); ` the ; should be removed

Comment: This token will absolutely not validate. Google only uses RS256 JWTs.

Comment: Looks like your are right. Now i get this exception _com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The custom token format is incorrect. Please check the documentation._ when implementing `mAuth.signInWithCustomToken(result)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(YetieActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() { ...`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. After reading @Jean-Philippe answer I was able to generate the token using `HS256` instead of `RS256`. But this was resulting in an invalid token every time even after changing credentials.

Using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) to debbug it, everything was correct but still getting invalid token from `firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token).catch(function (error) {}`.

After searching in github I found [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/issues/98). So I used double quotes instead of single quotes in `$private` and it worked with `RS256`.

```
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$service_account_email = env('ACCOUNT_EMAIL');
$private_key = env('ACCOUNT_SECRET');

class generateToken
{
    public static function generateNewToken($mysqli, $userID, $email)
    {
        global $service_account_email, $private_key;

        $name = '';
        $lastname = '';
        $hostOption = '';
        $now_seconds = time();

        $selectUserData = "SELECT username, lastname, hostOption FROM signup WHERE id = ? ";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($selectUserData);
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $userID);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($name, $lastname, $hostOption);
        $stmt->fetch();

        $payload = array(
            "iss" => $service_account_email,
            "sub" => $service_account_email,
            "aud" => "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
            "iat" => $now_seconds,
            "exp" => $now_seconds + (60 * 60),  // Maximum expiration time is one hour
            "uid" => strval($userID),
            "claims" => array(
                "username" => $name,
                "lastname" => $lastname,
                "email" => $email,
                "hostOption" => $hostOption,
            )
        );

        return JWT::encode($payload, $private_key, 'RS256');
    }
}
```

env.php:

```
$vars = [
    'ACCOUNT_EMAIL' => "admin@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    'ACCOUNT_SECRET' => "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nVERYLONGKEY=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
];

foreach($vars as $key => $value){
    putenv("$key=$value");
}
```

```
lindelius commented on 7 Aug 2018 • 
The reason is because the key contains new-line characters (\n) which are incorrectly handled when used within single-quotes, i.e. they are treated as the characters "\n" rather than actual new lines.
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of

```
$key = 'giant_key_goes_here';
token = JWT::encode($payload, $key, 'RS256');
```

use

```
define("FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY","giant_key_goes_here");
token = JWT::encode($payload, FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY, 'RS256');
```

Comment: can you explain your reasoning? how does that produce anything different?

Comment: I am no php expert, only sharing how I managed to solve a similar issue to the OP.